# NS2 AWK Scripting To Plot A Graph

Tags: awk, ns2

How,do I modify the code so that it will list out all the values by row and column?

Right now,the following codes below straight lead me to the answer of the calculation.

For example;

```
**GeneratedPackets = 2438
ReceivedPackets = 2386
Packet Delivery Ratio = 97.8671
Total Dropped Packets = 9
Average End-to-End Delay = 31.013 ms**
```

But I would like something like this,in order to plot my graph:

1 x1 y1

2 x2 y2

3 x3 y3

I have tried method like using such command:
awk -f [scriptname].awk [tracefilename].tr > graph.xgr

yet it shows only the calculation above.

```
    BEGIN {
seqno = -1; 
droppedPackets = 0;
receivedPackets = 0;
count = 0;
}
{
#packet delivery ratio
if($4 == "AGT" && $1 == "s" && seqno < $6) {
seqno = $6;
} else if(($4 == "AGT") && ($1 == "r")) {
receivedPackets++;
} else if ($1 == "D" && $7 == "tcp" && $8 > 512){
droppedPackets++; 
}
#end-to-end delay
if($4 == "AGT" && $1 == "s") {
start_time[$6] = $2;
} else if(($7 == "tcp") && ($1 == "r")) {
end_time[$6] = $2;
} else if($1 == "D" && $7 == "tcp") {
end_time[$6] = -1;
}
}  
END { 
for(i=0; i<=seqno; i++) {
if(end_time[i] > 0) {
delay[i] = end_time[i] - start_time[i];
count++;
}
else
{
delay[i] = -1;
}
}
for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
if(delay[i] > 0) {
n_to_n_delay = n_to_n_delay + delay[i];
} 
}
n_to_n_delay = n_to_n_delay/count;
print "\n";
print "GeneratedPackets = " seqno+1;
print "ReceivedPackets = " receivedPackets;
print "Packet Delivery Ratio = " receivedPackets/(seqno+1)*100
"%";
print "Total Dropped Packets = " droppedPackets;
print "Average End-to-End Delay = " n_to_n_delay * 1000 " ms";
print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Try to re-state your question.  Include an ns2 trace input where you define what elements of an ns2 trace file you would like to track to get your desired output.  The awk script you've included doesn't appear to be related to graphing at all.

Answer (score -2):

First of all you have a problem with the code......it will give an error most probably division by 0.....fix it by putting an `if(count)` just before dividing with count..
secondly use for loops to print it in a matrix format